# ASP pages inside main page

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

So i'm using main index page, with all the "main" links & css styles.

Then i have other .asp pages with only row code and i display those pages through my index page with:

```
Dim strPage
strPage = Request.QueryString("show")
If Len(strPage) = 0 Then
Server.execute("sign-in.asp")
Else
Server.execute(strPage & ".asp")
End if
```

So with this, if i go http://8.8.8.8/?show=start

It will show me start.asp with the styles etc. taken from the index.asp page.
But i have noticed, that my webpage is taking AGES to load.
Previewing it on localhost/?show=start is awesome&fast. But as soon it goes over public. Slow as hell. So seems like this code is slowing up my page somehow, is there some editing i can do OR configure my IIS correctly to handle this better?

(When i removed this and added the links, css etc. on each page it load alot faster like if it was localhost, but i can't go with that, because i edit the "main" links and css alot. And i want to edit them on 1 page only.)

Comment: Ofcourse if there is other type of code that kinda do the same as this, and known/tested for being better. Would be a pleasure to test.

Comment: Any reason you're using Server.Execute rather than Response.Redirect?

Comment: @John No Reason, how would it work with Response.Redirect? Can you give me an example code.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to have multiple pages (rather than only one index.asp page) but only one file to edit styles and other general setting, the best way is to include a setting file above all your pages like this

sample source of "setting.asp":

```
<style>
/*general styles goes here*/
</style>
<script src="setting.js"></script>
// and other general setting including js file and css files goes here
```

where this is a sample source of index.asp:

```
<html>
<!--#include file="setting.asp"-->
//index codes here..
</html>
```

and this is sample source of signin.asp:

```
<html>
<!--#include file="setting.asp"-->
//signin codes here..
</html>
```